# Add Text on Image using PIL

Tags: python, django, image, python-imaging-library

I have an application that loads an Image and when the user clicks it, a text area appears for this Image (using `jquery`), where user can write some text on the Image.  Which should be added on Image.

After doing some research on it, I figured that `PIL` (Python Imaging Library ) can help me do this. So I tried couple of examples to see how it works and I managed to write text on an image. But I think there is some difference when I try it using `Python Shell` and in web environment. I mean the text on the textarea is very big in px. How can I achieve the same size of text when using PIL as the one on the textarea?

The text is Multiline. How can i make it multiline in image also, using `PIL`?

Is there a better way than using PIL? I am not entirely sure, If this is the best implementation.

html:

```html
<img src="images/test.jpg"/>
```

its the image being edited

```js
var count = 0;
$('textarea').autogrow();
$('img').click(function(){
    count = count + 1;
    if (count > 1){
        $(this).after('<textarea />');
        $('textarea').focus();
    }   
});
```

the jquery to add the textarea.
Also the text area is position:absolute and fixed size.

Should i place it inside a form so i can get coordinates of textarea on image?
I want to write text on image when user clicks and save it on the image.

Comment: Why you want to write text on an Image using PIL (and I am Not sure if PIL helps in that). Isn't it good enough for you to show text in overlay, which is used most commonly in sliders.

Comment: I need it for a project i want the image to be saved. Pil can draw text on an image using ImageDraw, don't know if there is another way.

Comment: It will be helpful, If you can provide the Python code you are using?

Comment: not yet implemented in django. I tried to see how PIL works in interactive python console. Want to see if it works first and then transfer it in Django.

Comment: What's the $ symbol in your code?

Answer (score 225):

I think [ImageFont](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageFont.html) module available in `PIL` should be helpful in solving text font size problem. Just check what font type and size is appropriate for you and use following function to change font values.

```
# font = ImageFont.truetype(<font-file>, <font-size>)
# font-file should be present in provided path.
font = ImageFont.truetype("sans-serif.ttf", 16)
```

So your code will look something similar to:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import ImageDraw 

img = Image.open("sample_in.jpg")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
# font = ImageFont.truetype(<font-file>, <font-size>)
font = ImageFont.truetype("sans-serif.ttf", 16)
# draw.text((x, y),"Sample Text",(r,g,b))
draw.text((0, 0),"Sample Text",(255,255,255),font=font)
img.save('sample-out.jpg')
```

You might need to put some extra effort to calculate font size. In case you want to change it based on amount of text user has provided in `TextArea`.

To add text wrapping (Multiline thing) just take a rough idea of how many characters can come in one line, Then you can probably write a pre-pprocessing function for your Text, Which basically finds the character which will be last in each line and converts white space before this character to new-line.

Comment: That's my initial thought. So do i need my fonts to be in a specific folder in my webserver in order to work?I think yes. Wrapping text?is there a standard way or must i implement one?

Comment: You can keep the font file anywhere in your web server. Just make sure the path you provide is correct.

Comment: @lalit I tried your code on a Windows machine and I got an error for the font `self.font = core.getfont(file, size, index, encoding)
IOError: cannot open resource`. How can I provide path to the font file?

Comment: @LWZ, To run the above code, just make sure that the font file is in the current directory in which you are executing above code. In case you are using it into your program just specify the full path for your file e.g. 'C:\Windows\Fonts\sans-serif.ttf'. Other thing which you need to make sure here is to give appropriate read permissions to the file.

Comment: @LWZ /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf is an example of a font link on my PC.

cd /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ to see the options that you have.

Comment: font = ImageFont.truetype("./arial.ttf", 30);draw.textsize(msg, font=font);

Comment: I used `pip install pillow` to run this code with Python 2.7 (https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/).

Comment: You should prompt it to write a white string to the image, so when I write it to a white background, it took me a long time to find out the problem.  haha

Comment: @LWZ there was a bug with fonts that support non-ascii chars. update your pillow package

Comment: It does not work with font "sans-serif.ttf" (IOError: cannot open resource). But it does work with font "arial.ttf"

Answer (score 41):

Even more minimal example (draws "Hello world!" in black and with the default font in the top-left of the image):

```
...
from PIL import ImageDraw
...
ImageDraw.Draw(
    image  # Image
).text(
    (0, 0),  # Coordinates
    'Hello world!',  # Text
    (0, 0, 0)  # Color
)
```

Comment: I've also become aware that one can use .text without a specified font. But is there a way to specify size when one has not specified a font?

Comment: [`load_default`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageFont.html#PIL.ImageFont.load_default) doesn't seem to have a way to specify the font size. :/

Comment: How to control font size with this?

Comment: @Gulzar Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be any way to control the font size with this.

Answer (score 18):

You can make a directory "fonts" in a root of your project and put your fonts (sans_serif.ttf) file there. Then you can make something like this:

```
fonts_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'fonts')
font = ImageFont.truetype(os.path.join(fonts_path, 'sans_serif.ttf'), 24)
```

Answer (score 15):

**First install pillow**

```
pip install pillow
```

**Example**

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

image = Image.open('Focal.png')
width, height = image.size 

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

text = 'https://devnote.in'
textwidth, textheight = draw.textsize(text)

margin = 10
x = width - textwidth - margin
y = height - textheight - margin

draw.text((x, y), text)

image.save('devnote.png')

# optional parameters like optimize and quality
image.save('optimized.png', optimize=True, quality=50)
```

Answer (score 13):

First, you have to download a font type...for example: https://www.wfonts.com/font/microsoft-sans-serif.

After that, use this code to draw the text:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import ImageDraw 
img = Image.open("filename.jpg")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
font = ImageFont.truetype(r'filepath\..\sans-serif.ttf', 16)
draw.text((0, 0),"Draw This Text",(0,0,0),font=font) # this will draw text with Blackcolor and 16 size

img.save('sample-out.jpg')
```

Answer (score 12):

One thing not mentioned in other answers is checking the text size. It is often needed to make sure the text fits the image (e.g. shorten the text if oversized) or to determine location to draw the text (e.g. aligned text top center).
Pillow/PIL offers two methods to check the text size, one via ImageFont and one via ImageDraw. As shown below, the font doesn't handle multiple lined, while ImageDraw does.

```
In [28]: im = Image.new(mode='RGB',size=(240,240))                                                            
In [29]: font = ImageFont.truetype('arial')
In [30]: draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
In [31]: t1 = 'hello world!'
In [32]: t2 = 'hello \nworld!'
In [33]: font.getsize(t1), font.getsize(t2) # the height is the same
Out[33]: ((52, 10), (60, 10)) 
In [35]: draw.textsize(t1, font), draw.textsize(t2, font)  # handles multi-lined text
Out[35]: ((52, 10), (27, 24))
```

Comment: Thanks for highlighting this difference. I was indeed looking for getting the right text size in multi-lines.

Answer (score 8):

With Pillow, you can also draw on an image using the ImageDraw module. You can draw lines, points, ellipses, rectangles, arcs, bitmaps, chords, pieslices, polygons, shapes and text.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
blank_image = Image.new('RGBA', (400, 300), 'white')
img_draw = ImageDraw.Draw(blank_image)
img_draw.rectangle((70, 50, 270, 200), outline='red', fill='blue')
img_draw.text((70, 250), 'Hello World', fill='green')
blank_image.save('drawn_image.jpg')
```

we create an Image object with the new() method. This returns an Image object with no loaded image. We then add a rectangle and some text to the image before saving it.

Answer (score 4):

I recently had to implement the same thing. I have created a package on [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/pynter/) which might come in handy: [pynter](https://pypi.org/project/pynter/)

You can add text to an image with this steps:

1. Download an image: `curl https://i.imgur.com/XQCKcC9.jpg -o ./image.jpg`
2. Download a font: `curl https://fonts.google.com/download?family=Roboto -o ./roboto.zip ; unzip ./roboto.zip -d ./Roboto`
3. `pip install pynter`

```
from pynter.pynter import generate_captioned
font_path = './Roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf'
image_path = './image.jpg'
im = generate_captioned('China lands rover on Mars'.upper(), image_path=image_path, size=(1080, 1350),
                        font_path=font_path, filter_color=(0, 0, 0, 40))
im.show()
im.convert('RGB').save('drawn_image.jpg')
```

This will be the results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to download a font file and control the size of your text, first make sure you are using one of the later versions of pillow. You can use the following code to update your package:

```
pip install -U pillow
```

You may need to restart your kernel if you're using a jupyter notebook, then you can use something like this:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
base = Image.new("RGB",(500,300)) # create an empty image or load your image here
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(base)
# requires a newer version of pillow
font = ImageFont.load_default(size=50) # big text
color = (255,255,255) # RGB
draw.text((20, 20),"text here",color,font=font)
base
```

[image]

extra resources :
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageFont.html#PIL.ImageFont.load_default
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/text-anchors.html

Answer (score -4):

You can do with python using pillow or PIL module. [Learn how](https://rawcode.xyz/blog/How-to-add-text-in-Image-using-python.html)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33107278)

Answer (score -11):

**To add text on an image file, just copy/paste the code below**

```php
<?php
$source = "images/cer.jpg";
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
$output = "images/certificate".rand(1,200).".jpg";
$white = imagecolorallocate($image,255,255,255);
$black = imagecolorallocate($image,7,94,94);
$font_size = 30;
$rotation = 0;
$origin_x = 250;
$origin_y = 450;
$font = __DIR__ ."/font/Roboto-Italic.ttf";
$text = "Dummy";
$text1 = imagettftext($image,$font_size,$rotation,$origin_x,$origin_y,$black,$font,$text);
     imagejpeg($image,$output,99);
?> <img src="<?php echo $output; ?>"> <a href="<?php echo $output;    ?>" download="<?php echo $output; ?>">Download Certificate</a>
```

Comment: This is PHP, the question was about Python.