# Trying to add text to images and making gif using PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to make gif using `png` images and need to add some information on the data. I have posted the code and the image below. And I dont know what is up and why is it not working. The text does not appear on the image and instead the color of image changes. Which is very weird. I cannot figure out what is wrong with this.

```
import os
import sys
#import imageio as io
import re
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
#####################################################################################################
#key to sort the file_names in order
numbers = re.compile(r'(\d+)')
def numericalSort(value):
    parts = numbers.split(value)
    parts[1::2] = map(int, parts[1::2])
    return parts
############################################################

file_names = sorted((fn for fn in os.listdir('.') if fn.startswith('fileName')), key = numericalSort)

######################################################################
def gen_frame(path,time=time, counter=None):
    im = Image.open(path)
    alpha = im.getchannel('A')

    # Convert the image into P mode but only use 255 colors in the palette out of 256
    im = im.convert('RGB').convert('P', palette=Image.ADAPTIVE, colors=255)

    width, height = im.size
    print im.size
    # Set all pixel values below 128 to 255 , and the rest to 0
    mask = Image.eval(alpha, lambda a: 255 if a <=20 else 0)

    # Paste the color of index 255 and use alpha as a mask
    im.paste(255, mask)

    # The transparency index is 255
    im.info['transparency'] = 255

    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
    font = ImageFont.truetype(font = '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/DejaVuSans.ttf',size = 50,encoding="unic")
    draw.text((0.35*width,0.8*height),r"time =  %d"%time,fill=120,font = font )
    del draw
    # saving image
    return im
######################################################################
frames = []
counter  = 0
for filename in file_names:
    frames.append(gen_frame(filename,time=counter, counter=counter))
    counter += 1
######################################################################
name = os.path.basename(os.getcwd())
frames[0].save(name+"_timestep"+'.gif', save_all=True, append_images=frames[1::],loop = 5, duration = duration)
```

The fist image is an example of one i am using for making the gif. And the second image is the one i get as output from the code.

[image: This is the initial image. Similar images need to be used.]
[image: And this is what i get. instead of text on the image, the color of image is changed!]

------- Update -----

I managed to get the gif and fix the color with text (the problem was with the setting the transparency). 
But I have a problem now with the overlapping text in gif. 
The text that i draw overlap in different frames. I dont know now how to fix this issue.

[image]

Comment: Partial duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16373425/add-text-on-image-using-pil (make sure you have a color/alpha that's visible on the text)

Comment: Is the code as it stands in your question the current *"best"* code that generated the  current image?

Comment: yes. this is the one i used for the gif.

Comment: Where is `surfacearea` set?

Comment: sorry it was leftover code, i fixed that.